# How to increment date in JS date library

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I not able to increment the day by clicking on `+`?

```js
  var dayLength = 1000*3600*24;
  var current = new Date();
  console.log(current);
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    var a = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + dayLength);
    console.log(a);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `dayLength` to `new Date()` which is current date. You should add it to `current` variable.

```js
  var dayLength = 1000*3600*24;
  var current = new Date();
  console.log(current);

  $('button').on('click', function(){
    current = new Date(current.getTime() + dayLength);
    console.log(current);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
```

Note that I also change `valueOf` to `getTime` because per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf), `valueOf` is usually not called in user code.

Comment: Thanks Niyoko, this is working but can you please let me know what is the point of using `window.current`? why not `var current`?